# JQuery.animate(): HTML5 annimation with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a page with height animation on JQuery 2. But then element clicked, i've couldn't see this, because page momentaly scrolls to top of the page.
I have next page:

```
<a href="#" class="infoSlider" id="sl00013" onClick="onSliderClick('match0013', 'sl00013')"></a>
```

And JavaScript code is:

```
function onSliderClick(divId, slId) {

        var h1 = $( "div.bet .header" ).outerHeight(); 
        var h2 = $( "div.bet .line" ).outerHeight();
        var h = h1 + h2*4;

        $( "#" + divId ).animate({

                height: h
              }, 400, function() {
                    document.getElementById(slId).onclick = function() { onSliderClick_Up(divId, slId);};
        });

    }

    function onSliderClick_Up(divId, slId) {

        var h1 = $( "div.bet .header" ).outerHeight(); 
        var h2 = $( "div.bet .line" ).outerHeight();
        var h = h1 + h2;

        $( "#" + divId ).animate({
                height: h
              }, 400, function() {
                        document.getElementById(slId).onclick = function() { onSliderClick(divId, slId);};
        });

    }
```

Why its scrolls to top? And How I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any of these:

1. Remove the `href` attribute:
2. Return false from your event handler
3. Call `event.preventDefault()` as @Kos mentioned

No comment on why you're using `on*` attributes

Answer (score 0):

It scrolls to the top because you have `href=#` in there. If it was `href="http://google.com"` or anything like that, the browser would go there.

Attach your event handler with [`elt.on('click', function(event) {...})`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the link from behaving the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to prevent the default href by doing:

```
$('.infoSlider').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```